# I want to print 1 to 10 numbers if i enter 1,then 1 to 100 if 2,1 to 1000 for 3

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    int r,y,j;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter your number choice please:");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    r = pow(10,y);
    printf("the multiplier is: %d",r);
    for(j=1;j<r;j++)
    {
        printf("\n The number is %d",j);
        r=r-1;
    }
    getch();
}
```

output is:

```
Enter your number choice please:1
"The multiplier is:10
 The number is 1
 The number is 2
 The number is 3
 The number is 4
 The number is 5
```

I'm not getting my output till 10.What is the error in logic?

Comment: Yep, the given below logic works but int doesn't support your requirements. 10^10 - 10000000000 .

Comment: @Vinod Note: Op's code is only certain to work (after dropping `r=r-1`) for `0 <= y <= 4` as an `int` must have a range _at least_ only to 32767.  It _may_ work for 10 as the `int` range _could_ be 9.2e19 or even higher.  Best not to assume `int` range is 2e9.

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the `r=r-1;` from the `for` loop.

```
for(j=1 ; j<=r ; j++) // notice j<=r, instead of j<r
{
    printf("\n The number is %d",j);
}
```

If you leave it in, you're reducing the max value that you're looking to attain with `j`.

Comment: Yes, to expand on this, you are decreasing the condition to terminate the loop from within the loop, you are decrementing so in fact you are basically looping 5 times for 1, 50 times for 2, etc.

Comment: @JamesH Better explaination than I did :)

Comment: @user3414470 If you leave `r=r-1;`, then first time through the loop, `r=9`. Second time, `r=8`. And so on. So `j` catches up to it quicker, and exits the loop sooner.

Comment: Okay so you set r outside of the loop. For example, for an input of 1, you set r to 10. Then, while inside the loop, when you said r=r-1 you basically were decreasing r to 9 the first run, to 8 the second run, etc until the loop terminated at r=5. So your values of j were 1,2,3,4,5 when you were expecting 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(j = 1; j <= r; j++)  // Note the '=' sign to include r.
{
    printf("\n The number is %d",j);
    // r=r-1;  // Remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you could use the c library pow() mathematical function to do this:

```
//scan user input into int variable userInput 

for(int i=1; i <= pow(10, userInput);i++){
     printf("%d ,", i);
}
```

Comment: Should the user enter a `userInput` such that `pow(10, userInput) > INT_MAX`, this loop will never end.  Much better to calculate the upper limit once and saved as an `int`.

Comment: Being INT_MAX equal to 2147483647, I really doubt that the program could call for such a large number.

Comment: 1) C does not define `INT_MAX` equal to `2147483647`, but at _least_ `32767`.  2) "doubt that the program could call for such a large number" --> Hmmm, consider [Huge software bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501#Launch_failure), they had the same thought too.

Comment: Oh come on bro! This program is not for launching spacecrafts lol ! But what you say is real, always need to be careful with the data type used.

Answer (score 0):

two modification in your code:

```
for(j=1;j<r;j++)   ----> j <=r
{
    printf("\n The number is %d",j);
    r=r-1;   -->comment this line
}
```